# Jquery validate/jquery form requires 2 clicks to submit

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate, jquery-forms-plugin

I'm combining jquery validate() with the jquery form plugin to submit a form using Ajax. Everything works except that the submit button requires 2 clicks to submit. Any suggestions on how to resolve the issue?

In addition to return false recommended in the jquery form plugin (http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxSubmit), I've tried using preventDefault() and $.ajaxSetup({async:false});.

Also, the submit button is an image.

```
 <input id="submit" type="image" src="filename.jpg">
```

Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#form-id").validate({
  rules: {
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true
      }
    },
   messages: {
     email: {
       required: "Please enter a valid email address.",
       email: "Use this format: user@example.com."
     }
  },
  submitHandler: function () {
    $('#form-id').submit(function(){
    var options = { 
        success: showMessages
    }; 
$(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
    return false;
    });

}//end submitHandler
});//end validate
});//end document.ready
```

Plugins used:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxSubmit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add a `submit()` handler to the form in the `submitHandler`, as `ajaxSubmit` will submit it for you. Try this:

```
submitHandler: function () {
    var options = { 
        success: showMessages
    }; 
    $('#form-id').ajaxSubmit(options);
}
```

Comment: That fixed it. Makes perfect sense now that you pointed it out. Thanks!